# Dialogue Windows Look Wrong After Upgrade

Tags: unity, themes, dialog

I recently upgraded to 13.10, and I'm noticing that nearly all of the dialog windows look like they're from 1999. The trim looks right, but the buttons and everything else just look wrong.

Help me get back to the future...

[image]

[image]

Comment: They actually look like KDE saving dialod

Comment: Do you have a MyBook external hard drive? I know that sounds like a crazy question in this context, but there was a bug in `gnome-settings-daemon` recently where it would crash because MyBook returned some garbage data suggesting that it had a partially functioning keyboard. The result looked exactly like your screenshots.

Comment: Nope. But I'll try fooling around with gnome-settings-daemon a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK applications and QT applications are supposed to share the same theme by default, but this behaviour was broken (likely becauase I was messing about with a source install of qt). To get back the original behaviour:

`sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`

Then:

`qtconfig`

And setting gtk+ as the GUI style, solved this issue.

Comment: Issue solved for "most" applications... all except one (RStudio)